# Creating a java bean from a clojure map

Tags: java, clojure, javabeans

`clojure.core` provides `bean` that creates a clojure map from a java object but is there an inverse function that creates a bean (java object) from a map?

Comment: Do you mean to generate a new bean class from a map? Or to use the entries in a map to populate a bean of an existing bean class?

Comment: I was thinking to just return an Object. So `{:foo "bar"}` becomes `o.foo == "bar"`

Comment: That's not an `Object` because `java.lang.Object` has no fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you need exactly.

### Bean type exists in Java

In other words, you have (let's say) a Customer.class in your java project and you'd like to have that instantiated and filled in via Clojure based on the data in your map. This can be done simply via [java interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop).

### Bean type created in Clojure

You can use [AOT compilation](https://clojure.org/reference/compilation) to create a Javabean type, which will result in a .class file on the disk and can be used in a Java project (in the same way as any Java class, that does not have a corresponding Java source). You can use the [clj-bean](https://github.com/wjoel/clj-bean) library to avoid using [gen-class](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class) manually.

### Bean type created in Clojure - dynamically, without .class file

In this case, you can use [deftype](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deftype) to create the bean via dynamic bytecode creation (simply create methods for the getters and setters and move the data from-to the map).

You can find examples of all the above ways [in this project](https://github.com/wjoel/bean-benchmarks)

Answer (score 2):

There are various libraries that perform Clojure map <-> Java Bean translation, including one I authored called [bean-dip](https://github.com/uwcpdx/bean-dip/). Here's the breakdown in the README on the other options considered and what distinguishes [bean-dip](https://github.com/uwcpdx/bean-dip/):

> ...
>
> Existing translation solutions had feature gaps that lead us to create bean-dip: The `clojure.core/bean` built-in is one-way, uses uncached reflection and can't be configured. Cached reflection is available via [gavagai](https://github.com/ngrunwald/gavagai), but it's only one-way. There's [java.data](https://github.com/clojure/java.data), which is bidirectional, recursive and reflection-free, but it's not declarative making large translation layers hard to maintain.
>
> Bean-dip is:
>
> - Bidirectional: Translate from beans to maps and back again
> - Declarative: Just specify the bean class and a set of keys for corresponding maps
> - Recursive: Translation descends into nested beans when they also have translations defined
> - Reflection-free: Macro generates type hinted code that can be name checked at compile time via `*warn-on-reflection*`
> - Extensible: Translate values by key via implementations of multimethods
>
> Namespaced keys are supported making it easy to enforce contracts with Java APIs using specs...